# Replace Exchange 2013 with 2019 servers and HWLWC

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchange-2013, exchange-2019

My setup is hybrid with all mailboxes in O365.

On-prem we have 2 x 2013 servers used for management and mail relay.

I would like to add 2 x 2019 servers to initially run concurrently with the 2013 ones then move all apps and services that use relay from 2013 to 2019.

My question is:

Can I configure the new 2019 boxes connectors, certs etc same as the 2013 > test email relay and mailbox management > if all OK > move all apps to use 2019 as mail relay > power off 2013 servers (test nothing is pending) > **and then run HWC?**

Or do I need to run HWC after the new 2019 ar in coexistence?

And then run HWC again when after decommission the 2013 boxes?

HWC scares me a lot! I’m afraid to lose connection to O365…
Thanks m

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this case:[How can i upgrade the Exchange Server 2013 to Exchange Server 2019 with existing Hybrid Setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/403997/how-can-i-upgrade-the-exchange-server-2013-to-exch)

Install Exchange 2019 coexists with Exchange 2013 directly. After that, enable MRSProxy for your Exchange 2019 server:

```
Set-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -Identity "[<Server>\]EWS (Default Web Site)" -MRSProxyEnabled $true
```

After that, you will could rerun HCW to choose Exchange 2019 as hybrid server. If you want to uninstall Exchange 2013, you also need to configure virtual directory for Exchange 2019 and change public DNS(such as mail.domain.com, autodiscover.domain.com) record from Exchange 2013 to Exchange 2019.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't have any mailboxes on-prem do I still need to run MRSProxyEnabled command?
All my mailboxes have gone to 365 long time ago and all I use Exchange for is mail relay and management of accounts.